# How to update all value of DF2 in DF1 on basis of a cellname matched using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frame  i want update all value of  DF2 in DF1 on basis of  cellname matched. How i will find in pyspark. Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN2dz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
Create two dataframes

```
>>> a=[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b=[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(a, b), schema=['a', 'b']).show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  4|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+

>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(a, b), schema=['a', 'b'])
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b=[23, 34]
>>> df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(a, b), schema=['a', 'b'])
```

perform leftouter join & remove unnecessary columns

```
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  4|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+

>>> df2.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1| 23|
|  2| 34|
+---+---+
>>> df.join(df2, df.a == df2.a, "leftouter").drop(df2.a).drop(df.b).show()
+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|  1|  23|
|  3|null|
|  2|  34|
|  4|null|
+---+----+
```

Comment: But how will you remove those null values? You need to get all the data in the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I see in the two dataframes is in the `siteAddress` column. To be able to use the solution, you'll need to rename the `siteAddress` column in one of the dataframes. I am renaming the it in the second dataframe

```
df2= df2.withColumnRenamed('siteAddress', 'siteAddress_y')
```

After that you need to join the two dataframes and bring all the values in thesame dataframe.

```
df = df1.join(df2, on="Name", how="left")
```

Once you do that, you'll notice there are a bunch on `null` values in the dataset. We remove that using the coalesce function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df\
    .withColumn("UpdatedsiteAddress", F.coalesce(df.siteAddress, df.siteAddress_y))\
    .drop("siteAddress", "siteAddress_y")
```

The last line is to drop the extra columns